# How can I detect 2 cases - App recording screen and App using airplay

Tags: objective-c, ios11

How can I detect 2 cases - App recording screen and App using airplay?

I use the code below but I connect iPhone with another screen by HDMI. It's still returning YES while I don't enable recording screen.

Please help me resolve this.

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].isCaptured
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to determine there is an external display or not:

```
[[UIScreen screens] count] > 1
```